# MongoDB: Find Query for objects in an array

Tags: mongodb

My goals is to make a query for mongodb with my node.js server in order to take all the objects that respect a constraint in an array in my schema.

This is my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = mongoose.model(config.DATA_TYPE.ROOM, new Schema({
    name: String,
    guide: String,
    leader: String,
    partecipants_counter : { type: Number, default: 0},
    event_counter : { type: Number, default: 0},
    creation: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    partecipants: [],
    events : [ {
            id : Number,
            data: String,
            user: String
            } ]
}));
```

And I would like to do a query like:

```
SELECT events FROM room WHERE events.id > myInput
```

I start writing the query but the `events.id > lastEventId` condition is missing:

```
getLastEventsById: function(roomId,lastEventId,callback){
        Room.findById(roomId,{name: 0, __v: 0, guide: 0, leader: 0, creation: 0, partecipants_counter: 0, partecipants: 0},callback);
    }
```

Just for a bettere understanding, this is how it is working now my code (where I would like to remove my for loop):

```
getLastEventsFromId: function(roomId,lastEventId,callback){
        this.getAllEvents(roomId,function(err,data){
                var events_to_send = [];
                for(var i = lastEventId ; i < data.event_counter; i++) events_to_send.push(data.events[i]);
                callback(err,events_to_send);
        });
    },
getAllEvents: function(roomId,callback){
        Room.findById(roomId,{name: 0, __v: 0, guide: 0, leader: 0, creation: 0, partecipants_counter: 0, partecipants: 0},callback);
    }
```

Comment: To find in subdocuments of model use Model.find('events.id': <your id>)

Comment: as you can see from my for loop, I'm not looking for only one id but a sub-array of events that have id > lastEventId.

Comment: Try Query operators ( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ )
`Model.find('events.id': { $gt: <your id> })`